# Executing msp430x instruction but mcu is not a msp430x

Tags: c, gcc, contiki

I am using `sky` motes in `cooja`. The simulation for the same code worked fine for first few times but now suddenly the following `Contiki` error

```
     [java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageList.java:261) - Executing MSP430X instruction but MCU is not a MSP430X
     [java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageList.java:261) - 
     [java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageList.java:261) - Stack Trace: number of calls: 3 PC: $02076
     [java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageList.java:261) -   process_thread_ctimer_process (local in ctimer.c) called from PC: $0674e (elapsed: 23678)
     [java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageList.java:261) -   call_process (local in process.c) called from PC: $068f2 (elapsed: 23713)
     [java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageList.java:261) -   process_run (memset.c) called from PC: $04228 (elapsed: 24975)
```

Java Stack Trace:

```
     [java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageList.java:261) - org.contikios.cooja.ContikiError
     [java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageList.java:261) -   at org.contikios.cooja.mspmote.MspMote.execute(MspMote.java:341)
     [java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageList.java:261) -   at org.contikios.cooja.mspmote.MspMote.execute(MspMote.java:298)
     [java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageList.java:261) -   at org.contikios.cooja.motes.AbstractWakeupMote$1.execute(AbstractWakeupMote.java:47)
     [java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageList.java:261) -   at org.contikios.cooja.Simulation.run(Simulation.java:280)
     [java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageList.java:261) -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
     [java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageList.java:261) - Caused by: se.sics.mspsim.core.EmulationException: Executing MSP430X instruction but MCU is not a MSP430X
     [java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageList.java:261) -   at se.sics.mspsim.core.MSP430Core.emulateOP(MSP430Core.java:1079)
     [java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageList.java:261) -   at se.sics.mspsim.core.MSP430.stepMicros(MSP430.java:253)
     [java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageList.java:261) -   at org.contikios.cooja.mspmote.MspMote.execute(MspMote.java:337)
     [java]  INFO [AWT-EventQueue-0] (MessageList.java:261) -   ... 4 more
```

I am working with latest version of contiki and gcc. I have tried restarting cooja after `ant clean`. Any idea on how do I solve the problem?

Comment: In general, this kind of issues signal memory corruption somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As unexpected, the issue was not with the environment. I posted the issue [here](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/issues/2121) which helped me.

If the `MAX_PAYLOAD_LEN` is either too small or too long to fit in the array then this issue occurs. I had set the `MAX_PAYLOAD_LEN` to 19.